# Me gustaria saber como puedo dividir dos o mas contenedores y que en el css tengan las mismas proporciones

Tags: html, css, div

```html
<div id="contenedor">
    <div id="calculadora Costo-Beneficio">
        <div class="contenido">
            <h1 >Calculadora Costo-Beneficio / Herreria </h1>            
        </div>
    </div>             
</div>  
<div id="contenedor1">
</div>
```

Si pongo las mismas configuraciones en el CSS no queda bien, por eso voy moviendo, pero no queda perfecto. Hay alguna forma de poder emparejar ambos contenedores y su contenido sin hacer demasiadas configuraciones en el CSS? Gracias!

Comment: No he entendido del todo... Dices que si pones contenedor y contenedor 1 no tienen el mismo estilo?

Answer (score 2):

Hola para dividir un div en partes iguales, tantas como quieras, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
    <div class="padre">
        <div class="hijo"></div>
        <div class="hijo"></div>
    </div>
```

y el css:

```
    .padre{
    display:flex;
    }

    .hijo{
        flex-grow:1;
        flex-basis:0;
    }
```

De esta manera, todos los contenedores que se encuentren dentro de class="padre" se repartirán el espacio disponible de manera igual.

Puedes echarle un vistado a la documentación https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex y a las propiedades flex-grow , flex-basis y flex-shrink

Espero que te sea de ayuda